The code gives no output when I add a logo inside an arabic cover of my thesis
I have the following code
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
% LOGO
\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{logo}

 % TITLE OF THE THESIS 
 \begin{spacing}{1.5}
 \Huge
 \textthol{
   حول تعميم الموديولات شبه الحاقنة: موديولات $C4$  
  }
 \end{spacing}

 \vspace{1.5cm}
 \bf\texttt{بواسطة}  
 \vspace{0.5cm}
 \Large\textsl{
    حسين عيد عبد الجليل الصاوى إبراهيم
 } 
 \vspace{0.5cm}
 \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
 \large 
 \texttt{\bfseries 
 بكالوريوس العلوم فى الرياضيات \\
 جامعة القاهرة        
 }
\end{otherlanguage}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
\large \texttt{\bfseries
رسالة مرسلة 
إلى 
كلية العلوم \\
لاستيفاء متطلبات الحصول على \\
درجة الماجستير فى العلوم \\
(رياضيات بحتة) \\ 
قسم الرياضيات \\
كلية العلوم \\ 
جامعة القاهرة \\ }
\end{spacing}
\vspace{1cm}
\texttt{\bfseries تحت إشراف} \vspace{0.5cm} \\
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\textRL{\large\tt\bfseries أ. د. أحمد مصطفى الجندى} \\
\textRL{\normalsize\tt\bfseries قسم الرياضيات} \\
\textRL{\normalsize\tt\bfseries كلية العلوم} \\
\textRL{\normalsize\tt\bfseries جامعة القاهرة} 
\end{tabular}
 \hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\textRL{\large\tt\bfseries د. ليلى مصطفى سويف} \\
\textRL{\normalsize\tt\bfseries قسم الرياضيات} \\
\textRL{\normalsize\tt\bfseries كلية العلوم} \\
\textRL{\normalsize\tt\bfseries جامعة القاهرة} 
\end{tabular}
 \texttt{\normalsize\bfseries 4202}

 \end{titlepage}
 % END OF TITLE PAGE 
 \end{document}

Everything is fine before adding the line \includegraphics[scale=0.07]{logo} which adds the logo of the university. After adding this line the code gives no output. Why is this?
I appreciate any help.

you need to switch to LTR direction for the graphic (\beginL\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image}\endL). But be aware that arabtex is not compatible with a current LaTeX anymore, in texlive 2024 your example errors. I would recommend to use lualatex + babel, see e.g. https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-arabic.html
